# How to parse the json correctly. TypeError string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python and my first json parse is a fail.  I've tried so many combinations of code to pull 2 fields from the api request (StoreName and StockCount), but do not know where I am going wrong.  It should be easy, but I can't figure it out...Thank you.

Code so far...

```py
import json
import requests
bunn_stock_api = 'https://www.bunnings.com.au/api/v1/store/6432/nearest/3/'
bunn_product_id = '3020069'
get_stock_url = bunn_stock_api + bunn_product_id
stock_json_data = requests.get(get_stock_url).json()
stocklist = list(json.dumps(stock_json_data))
for item in stocklist:
    print(item[0]['StoreNumber']['StoreName'])
    print(item[0]['StoreNumber']['StockStatus']['StockCount'])
```

json response with extra non-important info removed

```
[
    {
    "StoreNumber":"6140",
    "StoreInfo":{
        "StoreNumber":0,
        "StoreName":"Nunawading",
        "CurrentTradingHours":{
            "IsOpen":true,
        }
    },
    "StockStatus":[
        {
        "ItemNumber":"3020069",
        "Code":3,
        "Message":"In stock",
        "StockCount":21
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "StoreNumber":"6230",
    "StoreInfo":{
        "StoreNumber":0,
        "StoreName":"Vermont South",
        "CurrentTradingHours":{
            "IsOpen":true,
        }
    },
    "StockStatus":[
        {
        "ItemNumber":"3020069",
        "Code":3,
        "Message":"In stock",
        "StockCount":15
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I know this question has been answered many times before, but I can't make any of the answers work on my json response.

Comment: The `json` method already returns a data structure parsed from the JSON in the response. `stocklist` isn't the list you think it is; it's a list of single-character strings resulting from you *re*-encoding that data structure.

Comment: You just want `for item in stock_json_data:`

Answer (score 0):

The `json` method already returns the list you want to iterate over, not a string that needs to be processed.

```
stocklist = requests.get(get_stock_url).json()
for item in stocklist:
    print(item[0]['StoreNumber']['StoreName'])
    print(item[0]['StoreNumber']['StockStatus']['StockCount'])
```

And if you *did* get the raw JSON from `requests.get(...).text()`, you would want to *decode* that value with `json.loads`, not encode it further with `json.dumps`.

```
json_data = requests.get(get_stock_url).text
stocklist = json.loads(json_data)
for item in stocklist:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner, but I can't get either of your answers to work. 
First gives me a 'TypeError 'str' object is not callable'
Second is a Key Error 0.  If I remove the 0 key, I still get 'TypeError
string indices must be integers'

Comment: Sorry; it's been a while since I used `text`, which is simply a `str`-valued attribute, not a method. As for the second problem, that depends entirely on what JSON you are getting back from the request, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Thanks @chepner  Added the response to the question.  Spent a few more hours on it.  I don't understand why this isn't working for me.  It's probably blindly simple, I just can't see it.

Comment: It's `item[0]['StoreInfo']['StoreName']`, not `item[0]['StoreNumber']['StoreName']`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and persistence @chepner, but I couldn't get it working.  I went back to Powershell and had the whole json parsed and output to csv code written and working in 20 mins.  I'll revisit why I can't get Python to work for me another time...thanks again